# DateTime type in angular is not accepted by HTML Date Picker

Tags: angular

I have a model with DateTime as type. I get the values from a webapi correctly. But when I place it in my input field as a default value on creating a Reactive Form, the input does not reflect the value. Please see my code below:

**Model**

```
export class Vehicle {
  id?: number;
  code: string;
  plateNumber: string;
  type: string;
  dateAcquired?: Date;
  datePosted?: Date;
  registrationMonth?: string;
  addedBy?: number;
}
```

**TS**

```
 createForm(): void {
    if (this.vehicle !== null) {
      this.codeControl = new FormControl(this.vehicle.code, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });
      this.plateNumberControl = new FormControl(this.vehicle.plateNumber, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });
      this.typeControl = new FormControl(this.vehicle.type, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });
      this.dateAcquiredControl = new FormControl(this.vehicle.dateAcquired, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });
      this.registrationMonthControl = new FormControl(this.vehicle.registrationMonth, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });
    } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 pr-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date Acquired</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              class="form-control"
              [formControl]="dateAcquiredControl"
              />
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Sample Result from API**
[image]

**Created Form with missing date**

[image]

**EDIT**

Using the advise given me, I think I am near the solution. But not yet there.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can try to use the [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

...

```
this.dateAcquiredControl = new FormControl(
  moment(this.vehicle.dateAcquired).format(
    'YYYY-MM-DD'
  ), {
  validators: [Validators.required],
  updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

Comment: Sir, what is the 'received_at'. I get an error there

Comment: Just missclicked when copied your code. I have edited

Comment: Sir I get the error of The specified value of "15/09/2020" does not conform to the required format , "yyyy-MM-dd". A little more help plase.

Comment: Ah, ok, just change the format to the following. I updated answer

Comment: Sorry but this time it's telling me 'the specified value 'yyyy-09-Tu' does not conform to the required format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Please try 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in my date template:

```
<ng-template #dateTmpl let-row="row" let-value="value">
  {{ value | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }}
</ng-template>
```

If that doesn't help you, could you please provide the existing html?

Comment: Now I see, thanks. Please use my second answer, I think it shoud help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your date time string to the format which is required by the datepicker. Here is a solution you can apply without using moment.

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-09-26T15:35:36.111608').toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: This is nice but it gives me an error of 'The specified value "9/15/2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".'

Comment: Thought you anted it in dd/mm/yyyy format. I updated my answer. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: This is actually awesome since you do not have to use moment. Just one thing though, the day gets 1 day behind. If its sept 16,2020, it becomes 15/09/2020. Hmmm...